# How to retrieve file from Azure File storage by AccountName and Key via REST API

Tags: azure

I am trying to retrieve a file(File type: csv or xml) by REST API from Azure File Storage, I have Storage Account Name & Key

e.g. account: testgetfilestorage
PW:ABC/abc82abc93f80+YCKJH23YGOabcabcabcabcbacbabcbabcabcbabcabcbacmZQ==

I use the "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" tool can view & download files successfully, but I test it on Postman was not successful, there is an error:
[view error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74lTE.jpg)

----------------------------------

```
Following is my setting on Postman


In Header:

x-ms-version: 2014-02-14


In URL:

GET https://testgetfilestorage.file.core.windows.net/integration/TestFile.xml
```

---

I can 100% sure the file exists on File Shares, but the error return 404.
May I know anything I did wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While I understand your account name and key are for a test file, it's still not a good idea to include your credentials in your post.  How are you setting up postman to download the file?

Comment: I have rewritten the account and PW to fake, so it is safe to show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests to Azure File Storage must be authorized. The reason you are getting the 404 error is because the requests are not authorized.

If you are using account name/key, you have two options:

1. **Create Authorization header and include `Authorization` header in your request**. Steps to compute authorization header is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key.
2. **Use Shared Access Signature**. Instead of using authorization header, you can create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token on the file and use that SAS token as part of the request URL. Steps to compute SAS token for a storage resource is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas. You can also create a SAS token on the file using Storage Explorer or Azure Portal. When creating SAS token, please ensure that it has at least `read` permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I followed your suggestion 1. to add an Authorization header in the API call, but it shows another error which is"<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b2f8bd70-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx49000000
Time:2022-06-28T06:28:01.8264626Z</Message>"

Comment: I have added in header ---> "x-ms-date:Tue, 28 Jun 2022 06:20:00 GMT" & "Authorization:SharedKey testgetfilestorage:ABC/abc82abc93f80+YCKJH23YGOabcabcabcabcbacbabcbabcabcbabcabcbacmZQ=="

Comment: You simply can't add your account key as authorization header. Please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) regarding instructions to compute it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Gaurav, I think you have answered my question in this post. I have opened another further question on the other post since it is more suitable to separate the question in order to keep it clear for people to understand, I would be grateful if you could also take a look at another post, thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72810548/signature-authentication-failed-when-call-api-to-azure-file-storage